# URL.getOrgDomainUrl() call from different places

Tags: apex

Is it possible to call not from ApexPAge, but for example from the RemoteAction, AuraEnabled method. either in the trigger is better, or in the batch in the Execute method

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What behaviors are you seeing? Please [edit] to add more context and make clear what you're asking.

Comment: in which cases the method will not work correctly, and where it is not worth it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`URL.getOrgDomainUrl()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm) method is documented to behave the same in all contexts:

> getOrgDomainUrl() always returns the same domain for your org, regardless of context. Use this method to build links to record URLs that work both in Lightning Experience and in Salesforce Classic, or as the domain when making API calls to your org.

It's not a callout, so you can invoke it pretty much wherever you want.

Comment: Oh...i missed it. Thank you